# How to make a master cmke and call it in other cmake files?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using cmake to build several projects and I have a similar structure in all of the: find and add boost, find and add opencv, ....

Currently, I am copy over all of codes to add these libraries to all of my cmakes.

Is there any way that I can write a master cmake and just add it to my cmake for each project so it add all of these libraries, possibly allowing me selecting them (similar to the say that in boost I can select which package I want to be added.

Comment: What's a cmkle? What's a "cod"?

Comment: `include(foo.cmake)` will be your friend. Simply create your own loading cmake scripts, and include them if needed.

Comment: I like how you only fixed the ones I pointed out. Why not engage some _effort_ and proof read your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the INCLUDE directive of Cmake

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html